# Android Maps: Installation error: INSTALL_FAILED_MISSING_SHARED_LIBRARY

Tags: android, google-maps

I'm trying to use Android Maps, following the instructions in [Hello MapView](http://developer.android.com/guide/tutorials/views/hello-mapview.html).

I've added `<uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />` in the Manifest, and I'm building against the 'Google APIs' target, which claims to be API version 7.

So I don't think I'm doing anything obviously wrong, but the project refuses to build with this error:

```
[2010-12-22 13:34:32 - FMS]Installing FMS.apk...
[2010-12-22 13:35:01 - FMS]Installation error: INSTALL_FAILED_MISSING_SHARED_LIBRARY
[2010-12-22 13:35:01 - FMS]Please check logcat output for more details.
[2010-12-22 13:35:01 - FMS]Launch canceled!
```

logcat is telling me the following (not very enlightening):

```
D/PackageParser(   55): Scanning package: /data/app/vmdl67147.tmp
I/PackageParser(   55): com.android.fms: compat added android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE
E/PackageManager(   55): Package com.android.fms requires unavailable shared library com.google.android.maps; failing!
W/PackageManager(   55): Package couldn't be installed in /data/app/com.android.fms.apk
D/AndroidRuntime(  206): Shutting down VM
```

It is possible I haven't set up the Maps API key correctly - when I [got it using `keytools`](http://code.google.com/android/add-ons/google-apis/mapkey.html#getfingerprint), I didn't specify an `alias_name`, though this didn't seem to cause an error.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This error arises from the fact that Google Maps not installed on your device/emulator.

Find another device (or install Google Maps on your device) or create AVD for emulator with Google Maps.

Comment: Ah - I hadn't seen this section: http://code.google.com/android/add-ons/google-apis/maps-overview.html#avdsetup

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that your project is set up to target API level 3 (android create project -t 3 ...), and that the AVD you are testing with is also set for API level 3 (or you are testing on an actual device with Google Maps on it).