# Installation error: INSTALL_FAILED_MISSING_SHARED_LIBRARY on Kindle fire

Tags: android, kindle-fire

I am trying to run the demo android maps project(MapsDemo) that comes along with the `Android SDK (Google API 10)` on my Kindle Fire but it throws this exception when the application is installing.

```
[2012-01-31 23:01:15 - MapsDemo] Installing MapsDemo.apk...
[2012-01-31 23:01:17 - MapsDemo] Installation error: INSTALL_FAILED_MISSING_SHARED_LIBRARY
[2012-01-31 23:01:17 - MapsDemo] Please check logcat output for more details.
```

and Log Cat

```
01-31 23:06:01.206: D/PackageManager(1372): Scanning package com.example.android.google.apis
01-31 23:06:01.206: E/PackageManager(1372): Package com.example.android.google.apis requires unavailable shared library com.google.android.maps; failing!
01-31 23:06:01.206: W/PackageManager(1372): Package com.example.android.google.apis couldn't be installed.
```

Same code works fine when i ran in my HTC Desire..

Is it possible to use KML and draw the routes using another way than using the Google APIs?

Anybody knows how to solve this issue ?

Comment: Well it seems obvious, the Kindle Fire doesn't have Google Maps installed, which is needed by this app... Find a way to install it (if possible, I'm not sure, but what I know is you'd need to root it), and it'll work

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android Maps: Installation error: INSTALL_FAILED_MISSING_SHARED_LIBRARY](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4509745/android-maps-installation-error-install-failed-missing-shared-library)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You cannot use the Google Maps add-on for Android on the Kindle Fire, as it does not exist.

You can add `android:required="false"` to your `<uses-library>` element in the manifest, then check at runtime to see if the `MapActivity` class is available in your virtual machine:

```
try {
  Class.forName("com.google.android.maps.MapActivity");
  // if you get here, you have Google Maps, so you can safely start a MapActivity
}
catch (Exception e) {
  // if you get here, you do not have Google Maps
}
```

What you do in the "you do not have Google Maps" case, as you will encounter on the Fire, is up to you.

Comment: Thanks, I tried this but did not work. getting java.lang.ClassNotFoundException

Comment: How can you get an unhandled exception if it's inside the try / catch and your catch is for all the exceptions (Exception)?

Comment: @kakopappa: If that is coming from `Class.forName()`, that will be caught by the above exception handler. If it is coming from something else, perhaps you are trying to use Google Maps before you perform the check I described in my answer.

Comment: This worked perfectly for me, but... The "splash" activity cannot be a subclass of MapActivity. This gives you the change to run @commonsware's code to detect whether the device supports Google maps (or not) and to take evasive action if not.