# Error while launching an android app

Tags: java, android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Android Maps: Installation error: INSTALL_FAILED_MISSING_SHARED_LIBRARY](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4509745/android-maps-installation-error-install-failed-missing-shared-library)

I was dealing with a Google map application and my code goes perfectly without any error; but when I started to run it, I am getting an error in my console:

```
 [2012-12-26 11:43:44 - MapsActivity] Installing MapsActivity.apk...
 [2012-12-26 11:43:45 - MapsActivity] Installationerror:INSTALL_FAILED_MISSING_SHARED_LIBRARY
 [2012-12-26 11:43:45 - MapsActivity] Please check logcat output for more details.
 [2012-12-26 11:43:45 - MapsActivity] Launch canceled!
```

This is my LogCat

```
  12-26 11:41:30.444: D/AndroidRuntime(263): >>>>>>>>>>>>>> AndroidRuntime START <<<<<<<<<<<<<<

  12-26 11:41:30.444: D/AndroidRuntime(263): CheckJNI is ON

  12-26 11:41:30.553: D/AndroidRuntime(263): --- registering native functions ---

  12-26 11:41:31.103: D/dalvikvm(215): GC_EXPLICIT freed 403 objects / 23512 bytes in 51ms

  12-26 11:41:31.124: D/PackageParser(58): Scanning package: /data/app/vmdl51455.tmp

  12-26 11:41:31.183: D/PackageManager(58): Scanning package com.example.google

  12-26 11:41:31.183: E/PackageManager(58): Package com.example.google requires unavailable    shared library com.google.android.maps; failing!

  12-26 11:41:31.183: W/PackageManager(58): Package couldn't be installed in /data/app/com.example.google-1.apk

  12-26 11:41:31.274: D/dalvikvm(58): GC_EXPLICIT freed 5947 objects / 302928 bytes in 78ms

  12-26 11:41:31.324: D/AndroidRuntime(263): Shutting down VM

  12-26 11:41:31.334: D/dalvikvm(263): Debugger has detached; object registry had 1 entries

  12-26 11:41:31.344: I/AndroidRuntime(263): NOTE: attach of thread 'Binder Thread #3' failed
```

Please suggest me!!

Comment: extend MapActivity instead of Activity in class file

Comment: The extended class is already MapActivity

Comment: *"my code goes perfectly without any error; but when I started to run it, I am getting an error"*  'This app. shows no bugs so long as you don't use it.'  That statement of yours seems very odd.  Did you mean perhaps that it compiles without errors?  Doing so is no guarantee of avoiding run-time errors.

Answer (score 6):

Create an emulator that will run with Google Apis. You have created an Emulator that doesn't support Maps, So it is throwing that error.

Go to AVD Manager, select your current emulator and click on edit button.

Then select Target as Google APIs of any version and save it. Restart your emulator and run the app, this time you don't get such error.

If that is not available then you have not completely updated your Android SDK. Please do that first